# Kivy compilation error "NoneType" object has no attribute "name"

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

```
##### main.py #####
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.app import Widget

from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ObjectProperty, StringProperty, ListProperty, BooleanProperty


class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MainScreen,self).__init__(**kwargs) # implements the features of a GridLayout (the base class of MainScreen)

    def save(self):
        '''Saves the data from the input to a text file.
    It is bound to the save button'''
        status = self.ids.workout1.ids.status.active
        workout = self.ids.workout1.ids.workoutInput.text
        day = self.ids.workout1.ids.dayInput.text
        time = self.ids.workout1.ids.timeInput.text
        with open('workoutData.txt','a') as f:
            f.write('%s, %s, %s, %s\n' %(status, workout, day, time))

        return None

    def totalTime(self):
        '''This function doesn't do anything right now! Add code to compute the total exercise time, and document it in this string'''
        return None

class WorkoutLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass

class AppScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    name = StringProperty('Num Num')   ### <----line 37
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(AppScreenManager,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = 'Num Num'          ### <----line 40


class WorkoutApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = AppScreenManager()
        print (sm.name)
#         sm.name="123"
        sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name='main'))
        sm.add_widget(SecondScreen(name='secondary'))
        return sm

if __name__=='__main__':
    WorkoutApp().run()



# NOTE: running is diff on diff platforms
# python main.py
# kivy main.py

##### part of workout.kv #####
<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            Label:
                text: 'Workout'
                size_hint_x: 2/3.
            Label:
                text: 'Day'
                size_hint_x: 1/6.
            Label:
                text: 'Time'
                size_hint_x: 1/6.

        WorkoutLayout:
            id: workout1
        WorkoutLayout:
            id: workout2
        WorkoutLayout:
            id: workout3
        WorkoutLayout:
            id: workout4
        WorkoutLayout:
            id: workout5
        WorkoutLayout:
            id: workout6
        WorkoutLayout:
            id: workout7

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            Button: 
                text: 'Save'
                on_press: root.save()
            Button:
                text: 'Next screen'
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'secondary'

<SecondScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            size_hint_y: 3/4.
            text: root.manager.name         ### <----line 45
#            text: 'Hello second screen!'   ### <----line 46
        Button:
            size_hint: (1/4.,1/4.)
            text: 'Back to main screen'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'main'

<WorkoutLayout>:
    size_hint_x: 1
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    CheckBox:
        id: status
        size_hint_x: 1/8.
    TextInput:
        id: workoutInput
        size_hint_x: 5/8.
    TextInput:
        id: dayInput
        size_hint_x: 1/8.
    TextInput:
        id: timeInput
        size_hint_x: 1/8.

TextInput:
    multiline: False
```

These are modified a bit from some sample codes online. When I compile, it says `"NoneType" object has no attribute "name"` , an error in line 45 in my kv file. I tried commenting in my main.py either line 37 or 40, but still got the same error.

If I comment in workout.kv line 45 and uncomment line 46, the code can be complied and line 46 in main.py can print out "NumNum", which means sm does have the attribute name.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a timing issue.  The logic in the kv file is executed during construction of the SecondScreen object, at which point in time its "manager" property has not yet been populated.  Since it hasn't been populated, it has a value of "None," and a NoneType doesn't have a name property.

Now, why does the manager property have a value of None?  Well, according to Kivy's documentation, this property is "set when the screen is added to a manager."  Which you're doing just *after* initialization.

So when you print the value out in main.py, the manager property has already been populated, but when you do it in the .kv file, which is invoked *during* initialization, you've got a NoneType in your property.

What can you do about this?
Well, one approach would be to change the offending line in the .kv to:

```
text: root.manager.name if root.manager else ""
```

This will cope with the manager property being None during initialization, and when the manager property is updated later, the text property should update automatically.  Perhaps there is a more elegant way to do this, though.